# Getting a 404 in Debugger for example.com/wp-admin/Array?

Tags: 404-error, tinymce

For some reason when I go to one of my clients WordPress installations, and I install a plugin that I made which has custom TinyMCE buttons, when they click on one of the buttons the popup appears but there's no text. In the JavaScript console of Google Chrome before I even click the buttons, there is the following:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - Array - http://mywebsiteurl.com/wp-admin/Array`

Could that have something to do with my plugin or their installation of WordPress? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken in PHP `Array` commonly comes up when array variable is wrongfully used where string is expected. But from this information I have trouble suggesting where exactly that can go wrong.